# Reading video metadata in C#

Tags: c#, metadata

I have this simple code which allows me to read any video file metadata, as you can see I can get almost everything like: video format, resolution, bitrate, ...etc,
but I can't find any info about video profile (high, main, level) which is very important for me!
Can anyone help please?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MediaInfoDotNet;
.
.
.
string fileNameAndPath = "F:\\test.mkv";
var myVideo = new MediaFile(fileNameAndPath);


.
.
.
if(myVideo.Video.Count > 0) {
var vid = myVideo.Video[0];
Console.Out.WriteLine("\nVideo format: " + vid.Format);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Video resolution: " + vid.Width + "x" + vid.Height);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Video BITRATE: " + vid.BitRate);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Video BitDepth: " + vid.BitDepth);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Video BitRateMode: " + vid.BitRateMode);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Video CodecCommonName: " + vid.CodecCommonName);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Video CodecId: " + vid.CodecId);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Video CompressionMode: " + vid.CompressionMode);
Console.Out.WriteLine("Video Duration: " + vid.Duration);
```

Comment: I do not think u can with that lib. It has t come from another source

Comment: @PerG I think you are right, I'm trying to use MediaInfo instead. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with the MediaInfoDotNet library

Answer (score 0):

Since about mid/end 2013 (versions 0.7.67 and newer), MediaInfoDotNet is able to provide the format profile:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("Format profile: " + vid.FormatProfile);
```